# NSPredicate to filter array of words to array of letters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

I am trying to make "weighted" list of letters as words are created. I have a massive list of words in an NSArray. For example I am trying to acquire a new NSArray filled with just the 3rd letters of all the words based off the first two letters entered.

So far I have...

```
NSArray *filteredArray;
if (currentWordSize == 0) {
    filteredArray = wordDictionary
}
else {
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@", filterString];
    filteredArray = [wordDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
}
```

And that works all good for putting whole words into the filtered array, but that isn't exactly what I need. Can anyone show me a way to just fill the `filteredArray` with just the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd letters of a random `NSString` from the `wordDictionary`?

EDIT: clarified my question.

Answer (score 2):

`NSPredicate` isn't what you're going to want to use for this.  `NSPredicate` simply evaluates objects based on one or more criteria and returns a yes/no result, so it can't be used to do things that actually manipulate the items being tested.

To grab the third letter of each string in an array and put the results in a new array would look something like this:

```
NSArray* wordDictionary;
NSMutableArray* filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString* aString in wordDictionary)
{
    if ([aString length] > 2)
        [filteredArray addObject:[aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 1)]];
    else
        [filteredArray addObject:@""]; //there is no third letter
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to take this one step further, and make the weighting more explicit, you could use an `NSCountedSet` to keep track of how many times each letter is used in that position: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html